# Restricting file type on blobstore upload in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using BlobstoreService for uploading a file to blobstore in AppEngine. How to restrict the content-type or file type of the file? For example, I only want to allow upload for image/jpeg files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to prohibit the user from uploading a prohibited filetype a-priori, because you can't tell what they're going to upload until they make the POST, and there's no clean way to terminate a POST request partway through. You can detect the filetype after they've uploaded the file, and delete the file from the blobstore if it's prohibited, however.

Comment: Nick, why not use the File API instead? You could filter by Mime Type and then decide to throw it away or save it to the blobstore.

Comment: @systempuntoout Because it doesn't gain you anything - the user's already uploaded the entire file to you by the time you can perform any checks. Using a regular upload also limits your filesize to what you can fit in memory and under the request size quota.

Comment: Yes I agree, although my concern was more on the billing side.

Comment: @systempuntoout You're paying for the bandwidth either way, and the storage cost for something you delete immediately is nearly zero. Besides, the total rate of people uploading stuff to have it rejected is going to be miniscule enough it's not worth optimizing for.

Answer (score 2):

Nick's answer is the correct one, of course, and you will need to do a full set of checks on the server side (type, size, whatever).  If you are really worried about it, though, you might consider doing some rudimentary error-checking on the client side.  JavaScript checking that the filename ends in jpg (plus variants) before form submittal is simple enough to implement.  Just remember to check on the server, too.